# Reuse strings in Java

Tags: java, user-input

I have been wondering if there is any way to reuse strings like:

```
import java.io.Console;

public class input {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();
        String input = console.readLine("Type username: "); //user input
        // name code
        // clear string
        String input = console.readLine("Hello, what would you like to do: ");  
        // other code
    }
}
```

By clearing the string at `//clear string`, so if you have a looped user-input if a thing does not come up true, it doesn't break.

Comment: Just declare it once, assign it as many times as needed

Comment: You could assign it a particular value in between, maybe "", in case you're worried about it having a problematic value from earlier

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is unlikely to save any memory in actual practice: if you use a new variable, the old variable will be available to be GC'd as soon as you stop using it.  Really, you're not getting any benefit by trying to reuse your variable here.

Comment: http://thecodelesscode.com/case/84

Comment: Louis, this was an example, I'm using in in a loop in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String input= console.readLine("Type username: "); //this is legal
```

//however the next line wouldn't be
String input = console.readLine("Hello, what would you like to do: ");

//instead the code should like this:

```
String input= console.readLine("Type username: ");
```

input = console.readLine("Hello, what would you like to do: ");

this replaces the string input and you are able to 'reuse' it

Answer (score 5):

You can't declare the same variable multiple times. You can, however, re-assign as often as you want provided you haven't declared it final.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you're redeclaring `input`.  Instead, you can just reassign:

```
input = console.readLine("Hello, what would you like to do: ");
```

NB: You will be unable to reassign if the variable is declared as `final`.

The only time that redeclaring variables is an option is when the variable is declared inside of a `loop`.  It may make sense to do this if the variable will not be used outside of the scope of the `loop`, ie:

```
while(someCondition)
{
     String s = ...;
}
```

Otherwise redeclaring variables is semantically forbidden.

Comment: It is semantically forbidden actually. There is no syntax about that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare it each time, only once.

Answer (score 0):

In java objects get deleted automatically so if you reassign your local reference to the first string, it gets deleted by the garbage collector because no one is using it any more.

The special think in java is, that strings are immutable. That means, the object string cannot be changed and has the value it has until it gets deleted by the garbage collector.

In your example above, you actually have to reassign

```
input = console.readLine("Hello, what would you like to do: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-declaring the value of a String will always replace the existing value. So there is no need to "clear" the value of a String if you are simply giving it a different value (e.g. re-declaring the value of an int")

The problem with this code in specific is that you declared the String "input" twice in this code. Declaration is only needed once in any class. You can change the value by simply calling

```
input = console.readLine("Hello, what would you like to do: ");
```

This will reassign the value to input.

Comment: That's assigning, not re-declaring.

Answer (score 0):

"Clearing a string" is as simple as

```
input = "";
```

You don't need to redeclare the variable.  As long as you're in the scope of the variable (same method, or if the variable is class-wide, class), you're fine.